# Stacked Bidirectional LSTM model

Tags: lstm, tensorflow2.0, recurrent-neural-network

The following is the stacked bidirectional LSTM model using TF2.

```
class ForexPredictionModel(tf.keras.Model):
def __init__(self, seg_len, **kwargs):
    super(ForexPredictionModel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.lstm1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(filter_len, input_shape = (-1, -1, numchannels)))
    self.lstm2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(filter_len))
    self.lstm3 = Bidirectional(LSTM(filter_len))
    self.dense = Dense(256, activation="relu")
    self.out = Dense(num_classes, activation="sigmoid")

def call(self, x):
    x = self.lstm1(x)
    x = self.lstm2(x)
    x = self.lstm3(x)
    x = self.dense(x)
    x = self.out(x)
    return x
```

The error is

```
    File "StageN_winning_bidirnstackedlstm.py", line 96, in <module>
    model.build(input_shape=(batch_size, seqlen, numchannels))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 413, in build
    self.call(x, **kwargs)
  File "StageN_winning_bidirnstackedlstm.py", line 89, in call
    x = self.lstm2(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/layers/wrappers.py", line 583, in __call__
    return super(Bidirectional, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1020, in __call__
    input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 214, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError('Input ' + str(input_index) + ' of layer ' +
ValueError: Input 0 of layer bidirectional_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (8, 256)
```

Why input is not imcompitable?

Comment: Are you sure indentation is correct in your question?

Comment: Yes correct, identation is not issue in this case